# How can I implement IEnumerator<T>?

Tags: c#, generics

This code is not compiling, and it's throwing the following error:

> The type 'TestesInterfaces.MyCollection' already contains a definition for 'Current'

But when I delete the ambiguous method, it keeps giving other errors.

Can anyone help?

```
public class MyCollection<T> : IEnumerator<T>
{
    private T[] vector = new T[1000];
    private int actualIndex;

    public void Add(T elemento)
    {
        this.vector[vector.Length] = elemento;
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        actualIndex++;
        return (vector.Length > actualIndex);
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        actualIndex = -1;
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose() { }

    public Object Current
    {
        get
        {
            return Current;
        }
    }


    public T Current
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                T element = vector[actualIndex];
                return element;
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException e)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're implementing `IEnumerator` instead of `IEnumerable`? This implementation seems to be asking for issues with threadsafety (multiple enumerations look like they will fail spectacularly)

Comment: yeah, I'm just playing with the collections to understand the inner workings, not just how to use them :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding `IEnumerator<T>`. Typically, collections implement `IEnumerable<T>`, not `IEnumerator<T>`. You can think of them like this:

- When a class implements `IEnumerable<T>`, it is stating "I am a collection of things that can be enumerated."
- When a class implements `IEnumerator<T>`, it is stating "I am a thing that enumerates over something."

It is rare (and probably wrong) for a collection to implement `IEnumerator<T>`. By doing so, you're limiting your collection to a single enumeration. If you try to loop through the collection within a segment of code that's already looping through the collection, or if you try to loop through the collection on multiple threads simultaneously, you won't be able to do it because your collection is itself storing the state of the enumeration operation. Typically, collections (implementing `IEnumerable<T>`) return a separate object (implementing `IEnumerator<T>`) and that separate object is responsible for storing the state of the enumeration operation. Therefore, you can have any number of concurrent or nested enumerations because each enumeration operation is represented by a distinct object.

Also, in order for the `foreach` statement to work, the object after the `in` keyword, *must* implement `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>`. It will not work if the object only implements `IEnumerator` or `IEnumerator<T>`.

I believe this is the code you're looking for:

```
public class MyCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private T[] vector = new T[1000];
    private int count;

    public void Add(T elemento)
    {
        this.vector[count++] = elemento;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return vector.Take(count).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: i im not really planning to use this collection im creating... I'm only doing this to try to understand the functioning of the IEnumerator and IEnumerable... anyways your implementation throws  *'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<T>' requires 1 type arguments*

Comment: You need both `using System.Collections;` and `using System.Collections.Generic;` if your code uses both `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: thats true, im sorry. Your example of how thinking IEnumerator<T> and IEnumerable<T> helped me. Thanks

Comment: @MichaelGunter `It is rare (and probably wrong) for a collection to implement IEnumerator<T>.` Is this [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_4) one of them?

Comment: @ibubi : No. The code in that example shows what I would expect all `IEnumerable<T>`/`IEnumerator<T>` implementations to be -- separate classes for the `IEnumerable<T>` and the `IEnumerator<T>`.

Answer (score 9):

You need to define the interface the current is implementing.

```
Object IEnumerator.Current
{
    //
}

public T Current
{
    //
}
```

This way your class has 2 `Current` properties. but you can access them both.

```
MyCollection<string> col = new MyCollection<string>();
var ienumeratort = col.Current; //Uses IEnumerator<T>
var ienumerator = (IEnumerator)col.Current; //uses IEnumerator
```

Comment: More typical is to make the strong-typed property public, and only use explicit interface implementation for the `object`-type property.

Answer (score 1):

I think with C# 2.0 onwards, you have a very easy way of implementing iterator and compiler does a lot of heavy lifting behind the scene by creating state machine. It's worth looking into it. Having said that, in that case your implementation would look something below:

```
    public class MyCollection<T>
    {
        private T[] vector = new T[1000];
        private int actualIndex;

        public void Add(T elemento)
        {
            this.vector[vector.Length] = elemento;
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> CreateEnumerable()
        {
          for (int index = 0; index < vector.Length; index++)
          {
            yield return vector[(index + actualIndex)];
          }
       }
   }
```

I am not sure about the purpose of actualIndex though - but i hope you get the idea.

After proper initialization of MyCollection, below is snippet somewhat looks like from consumer perspective:

```
MyCollection<int> mycoll = new MyCollection<int>();
            foreach (var num in mycoll.CreateEnumerable())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(num);
            }
```