# Launch all URLs in webbrowser c# 2 seconds to 2 seconds

Tags: c#, facebook

I am going to make a facebook applications in c#. I extract group ids to textbox4.Text and i want to go to  all website 2 seconds to 2 seconds..
it means 1 website display 2 seconds after 2 seconds it will redirect to another website...

I use timer to get 2 seconds duration and I want to go to all website using a loop or something.. I use for loop for that but it is not printing all website. 
it prints only website in last...

Here i extract group IDs this is working no problem

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.Text = webBrowser1.DocumentText;
    textBox3.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
        richTextBox1.Text.Split('/', ' ', '?')
                .Where(m => m.Length > 14 && m.All(char.IsDigit)));
    label3.Text = (textBox3.Lines.Length).ToString()+" Groups";
}
```

problem is following code when i am going to launch these one by one.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    textBox3.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
        richTextBox1.Text.Split('/', ' ', '?')
            .Where(m => m.Length > 14 && m.All(char.IsDigit)));
}

IEnumerator<string> websites;

private void button3_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    textBox4.Text = textBox3.Text;
    string[] groups = textBox4.Text.Split('\n');

    for (int i = 0; i < textBox3.Lines.Length; i++)
    {
        websites = new List<string> {"https://mbasic.facebook.com/groups/"+groups[i]}.GetEnumerator();
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        websites.MoveNext();
    }
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate(websites.Current);
    timer1.Enabled = websites.MoveNext();
}
```

Please anybody fix this issues.

Comment: So what exactly is this "wrong" code doing and what is it supposed to be doing instead?

Comment: I can’t see this having any real-world application for non-shady purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are overwriting your websites-object in every loop with the following line:

```
websites = new List<string> {"https://mbasic.facebook.com/groups/"+groups[i]}.GetEnumerator();
```

That's why it only prints the last website.

Have a look at [How can I add an item to a IEnumerable collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210295/how-can-i-add-an-item-to-a-ienumerablet-collection)

Furthermore this could help you, too: [IEnumerable vs. IEnumerator and implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18104624/how-can-i-implement-ienumeratort)

Comment: yes. my code is wrong. I can see i am overwriting the code. I need to print https://mbasic.facebook.com/groups/"+groups[i] line in a loop to get all groups like   https://mbasic.facebook.com/groups/"+groups[0],https://mbasic.facebook.com/groups/"+groups[1],
https://mbasic.facebook.com/groups/"+groups[2],
https://mbasic.facebook.com/groups/"+groups[3],...etc . do you have any idea to print like that?

Comment: Use List<string> strings = new List<string>();

Comment: Inside your for-loop add each url by: strings.add(url)

Comment: Finally start your timer. Sorry for my bad code formatting. I'm using my mobile phone.

Comment: In words: Add your url strings to a List. After that "initialize" your websites objects with this list. But do not use IEnumerator<string> for websites. Better use IEnumerable<string>

Comment: hi i set as you said. please see, what is the wrong of this clicking [this](https://scontent.fcmb2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/24909691_149915155774236_7907890880088530804_n.jpg?oh=91026e4c1b40cb86859dd09bfd8dbe09&oe=5AC05157)

Comment: websites = strings.AsEnumerable();

Comment: your method is right. i [FIX THE issue Click here](https://scontent.fcmb2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/25289618_149916439107441_7614206290565424235_n.jpg?oh=df6b25686d8cdc9ca4c7eb3ecb6ac5d4&oe=5A9001E7)

Comment: Yes @Imashi-Ekanayaka fixed your foreach-loop the right way. But I think you should use .AsEnumerable(); instead of .getEnumerator()